# Ошибка при выборе JDK "The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK"

Tags: java

Всем привет. ОС XUbuntu 16.04, IntelliJ Idea 2018.2, версия java 11. Установил java вручную по инструкции [здесь](https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/java), результат команд в терминале:

```
$ java --version
```

java 11.0.1 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)

```
$ whereis java
```

java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java

при попытке указать путь к jdk в intelij edea выдает окно с сообщением "The selected directory is not a valid home for JDK". Подскажите что не так, как исправить.
скриншоты:
[image: скрин 1] [image: скрин 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исполняемый файл java лежит не в JAVA_HOME. Скорее всего путь /usr/lib/jvm/default-java

Comment: заработало, добавил путь в переменную PATH. Спасибо.

Comment: @Ramil [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).